# How to calculate errorbar for a histogram created randomly?

Tags: sampling, random-variable, standard-error, computational-statistics, measurement-error

A cubic region of space is filled with many spheres of different sizes. Perpendicular to two of the surfaces of this cube, we send some known number of random beams, *some_number*, based on the ''continuous uniform'' distribution over the half-open interval [0, 1) across this region using the module `numpy.random.random(size=(some_number, 2))`. And then, we identify all the spheres intersecting these random beams. We then categorize spheres in terms of their sizes in 7 bins in x axis. As you expect, there will be a geometric-like distribution corresponding to the frequency of spheres (y-axis) in each size bin (x-axis). To establish an errorbar for each data point on this plot, one needs to have lots of realizations of the same fixed number of random beams. Assuming that such tool is not available, is there any way to create an uncertainty for each one of the data points?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what distribution the random beams follow and on the exact shape of the region in which the spheres are confined.  If you need to solve a specific problem, then please supply details.

Comment: I did specify those information. Do you think this is doable theoretically?

Comment: Nice!  This is closely related to practical problems of subsurface geological exploration.  See Tang & Quek, *Statistical Model of Boulder Size and Fraction,* J. Geo. Engr., Vol. 112, No. 1, January, 1986.  (There, your beams are drill holes.)

Comment: @whuber, thank you! I am still trying to make connection between relationships in that paper.